# How to get first element from jsonb array in PostgreSQL Procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Inside a procedure need to get first element of jsonb array;

`SELECT jsnArrayData[0] INTO jsnItem;`

Here is my complete procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_update_set_document_code(jsnArrayData JSONB[]) AS $$
    DECLARE
        jsnItem JSONB;
    BEGIN
        SELECT jsnArrayData[0] INTO jsnItem;

        -- Logic here

        RETURN;

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Tried jsnArrayData[0], jsnArrayData->>0, JSONB_PATH_QUERY_FIRST(arjSetDocumentCode, '$[*]')

Answer (score 1):

`jsnarraydata` is an array of JSON, not a "JSON array", so you need to follow the rules of accessing [Postgres array elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING), not the ones for JSON arrays.

```
jsnitem := jsnarraydata[0];
```

This will pick the first array element of the parameter and assign it to your variable. If you need to work with the value inside `jsnitem` that is a completely different question (and given the lack of detail in your question can't really be answered)